# Original instance terminated, can't RDP into new instance with EBS snapshot restored volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, amazon-ebs

I'm new to EC2 and I mistakenly terminated an instance that was setup the way that I like and had taken EBS snapshots of (root volume).

I created an AMI based on the snapshot I wanted, but when I launch a new instance, I no longer am able to decrypt the Administrator password for the volume. I tried [these steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Config.html) but couldn't get it to work even though I have the pem for the key file.

Is there anyway to recover this Administrator password?

Answer (score 1):

The password for this is the same as the one you took the snapshot from.

If you still have that password you can use it to connect, otherwise you will need to reset it.

All hope is not lost, there are a [few official solutions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-admin-password/) used to reset the password.

Comment: Does the volume being encrypted or not change anything?

Comment: No this would not change the operation